# CakePHP and sending emails. Am I doing it right?

Tags: php, email, cakephp, smtp

I am using CakePHP to write a web app and one of the requirements is to send users' emails after registration.
I had to create an email account on our server and then send the emails using smtp authentication, otherwise, google and yahoo (at least) refused to read my emails.
Does this come with major trade offs? As in speed of the app or delivery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use mail a lot in my apps, and have eventually settled on delivery by `mail` rather than `smtp`. The reason for this is that some of the servers we use can have unpredictable behaviour when sending to themselves.

As far as I know, there are no performance tradeoffs.

By choice, however, I would use `smtp`.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the proper headers in the mail it should not be refused. Also, you can send the mains from valid account, and this way I think google and yahoo should accept it.